# SQL Server Management Studio won't start

Tags: sql-server

A coworker of mine has this problem, apparently after installing Re#, which seems totally irrelevant. But perhaps it isn't.

Could not load file or assembly "SqlManagerUi, Version=9.0.242.0..." or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (mscorlib).

Why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Management studio requires the .Net framework.  Try removing/reinstalling it.

Answer (score 5):

I was with a similar problem, i could not open my SQL Server Management Studio.
This steps works for me:

In file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe.config`, erase the item `<NgenBind_OptimizeNonGac enabled="1" />`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- ...snip... -->
    <runtime>
        <!-- ...snip... -->
        <!-- Remove this line (~line 38) -->
        <NgenBind_OptimizeNonGac enabled="1" />
        <!-- ...snip... -->
    </runtime>
    <!-- ...snip... -->
</configuration>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Odd as it seems, this is the answer, as sweated out on another thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237086/sql-server-management-studio-18-wont-open-only-splash-screen-pops-up

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the .Net framework didn't help me, but these next steps did. I had to completely uninstall and reinsall the shared components, but it's pretty hard to find out how to do that.

Make sure you have the installation media handy. In my case that's the unzipped folder from the downloaded SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU ed 2014.exe

1. First, through your Control panel -> Uninstall a program, find 'Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (x64)'.
2. Right-click and select Uninstall/Change.
3. When you're presented with a dialog with the options to 'Add', 'Repair' or 'Remove' the product, select the last (don't worry, your SQL Server won't be touched if you follow these steps carefully.
4. From the initially blank drop-downlist select << Remove shared features only >>
5. Follow all steps from there, and you are now able to reinstall the shared features.

Answer (score 0):

was there any installing/uninstalling of VS involved? Don't get me started on SQL 2005 and VS intall conficts.

Comment: So you ask a clarification question and then do not want to talk about a possible solution. Why exactly did you write an answer instead of using your commenting privilege? (Ah, probably because back then you did not have that privilege. Nevertheless, time to review.)